# Selecting column like Primary Key in View from PostGIS using PyQGIS?

Tags: postgis, pyqgis

Postgresql doesn't support Primary Key in views.
When I load a postGIS view in QGIS "manually", I can choose the column that will be the Primary Key, but I would like to know if I can select a column as Primary Key when I load it using pyQGIS script.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have found the answer reading the QGIS API

This is the method:

```
void QgsDataSourceURI::setKeyColumn (QString column )
```

this is my example:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection('localhost', '5432', '-mydatabase-', '-myowner-', '-mypasswd-')
uri.setDataSource('public', 'parcelas', 'the_geom')
#public: schema, parcelas: the view, the_geom: spatial column
uri.setKeyColumn('id') #name of my primary key

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), '-name_of_the_layer-', 'postgres')
if vlayer:
  print "All Ok!"

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```