# Displaying pre-styled pie charts in QGIS and with standalone pyqgis script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, style, qgis-2

I’m trying to create a `PNG` image containing pie charts as style for a layer using a standalone pyqgis script (QGIS v2.18.14).

The script works fine with other layers and style files, but the layer containing the pie charts stays blank.

I suspect this is caused by one or several of the following reasons:

1. A bug might be preventing pyqgis to correctly apply the QML style
   file. The bug can be reproduced in QGIS as follows:

   - a.   Open `Layer Properties` for a layer containing `centroid_geo`/`point` spatial type, and set style for layer to include diagrams (pie charts) and custom colors by  attribute
   - b.   Save the style as `QML`
   - c.   In a new project containing the same layer with different styling, load the previous QML file a first time. The `Layers Panel` will automatically update the point’s style according to the QML file, but not the colors for the selected attributes (see screenshot).
   - d.   Repeat the import of the `QML` file in the `Layers Properties` a second time, and the colors in the `Layers Panel` will now automatically update with the new colors from the QML file (see screenshot), but they will still not update in the `Layers Properties` window under `Assigned attributes` (right side of the screenshot).
   - e.   When clicking `Apply` or `OK` in the `Layers Properties` window, the former style is finally adopted and overwrites the style file’s colors in the `Layers Panel`
   - Note: i figured out that a trick to apply the styling from the QML is to do steps a-d, then instead of clicking `Apply` or `OK`, click `Cancel`, then reopen the `Layers Properties` window, and then only are the updated colors visible in the window, and can be applied to the map by clicking Apply/OK.

[image: annotated screenshot describing bug]

2. Maybe pie charts cannot be rendered using pyqgis simple rendering,
   which is the method I’m using (cf code below)
3. Maybe I’m doing something wrong/missing something in the pyqgis script.

So far I also tried repeating three times the `lyr_ecs.loadNamedStyle(...)` command hoping the workaround for the bug in the QGIS GUI might work in a similar way from the script, but this didn't work.

```
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()

# Load project
QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo(root_path + project_path))
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
    # set host name, port, database name, username and password
    uri.setConnection("{}".format(host), "{}".format(port), "{}".format(dbname), "{}".format(user), "{}".format(password))


##########################################################
        #Add new layer to image
##########################################################
        # SUBSECTORS       
        # Set database schema, table name, geometry column and optionally a subset (WHERE clause)
        uri.setDataSource(schema_name2, "geo_girec", "geom", "numero IN ('{}')".format(geo_girec_numero)) #('2800080','2800152','2800079')") 
        uri.setKeyColumn('numero')

        # Load layer to PyQgis environment
        print "loading SUBSECTORS layer"
        lyr_subsectors = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "subsectors2", "postgres")

        # Check if layer was correctly loaded to PyQgis and if so, process its style
        if not lyr_subsectors.isValid():
            print "Layer 'subsectors2' failed to load! Probably not existent."
        else:
            print "Layer 'subsectors2' loaded!"        
            # Add layer to the registry                    
            QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr_subsectors)
            print "QgsMapLayerRegistry correctly added map layer lyr_subsectors"

            # Load style file corresponding to the layer
            lyr_subsectors.loadNamedStyle(root_path + '/layerStyles/citygml/subsector_style_gray' + '.qml')



##########################################################
        #Add new layer to image
##########################################################
        #First check if the BUILDING_ECS_ENY_VIEW is to be used in the requested style
        if 'qml_name_ecs' not in globals():
            print "Pies are not requested by user, moving on"
        else:
            # BUILDING_ECS_ENY_VIEW        
            # Set database schema, table name, geometry column and optionally a subset (WHERE clause)
            uri.setDataSource(schema_name, "building_ecs_eny_view", "centroid_geo", "scenario_id = " + scenario_id + " AND cityobjectgroup_id = " + cityobjectgroup_id)

            # Define primary key of view (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151686/selecting-column-like-primary-key-in-view-from-postgis-using-pyqgis)
            uri.setKeyColumn('citymodel_id,scenario_id,cityobjectgroup_id,blg_id')

            # Load layer to PyQgis environment        
            print "loading BUILDING_ECS_ENY_VIEW layer"
            lyr_ecs = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "building_ecs", "postgres")

            # Check if layer was correctly loaded to PyQgis and if so, process its style        
            if not lyr_ecs.isValid():
                print "Layer 'building_ecs_eny_view' failed to load! Probably not existent."
            else:
                print "Layer 'building_ecs_eny_view' seemingly loaded!"
                # Add layer to the registry
                QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr_ecs)
                print "QgsMapLayerRegistry correctly added map layer lyr_ecs"

                # Set canvas extent  
                canvas.setExtent(lyr_ecs.extent())

                # Load style file corresponding to the layer
                lyr_ecs.loadNamedStyle(root_path + '/layerStyles/citygml/{}'.format(qml_name_ecs) + '.qml') #e.g. "2.5d-height_energy-standard.gml"

                ##################################3
                #NOTE: i tried repeating the line above three times here to mimick the workaround from the bug described above in the QGIS interface, but this didn't work..
                ##################################

            # Set layer set
            lst = [lyr_ecs.id(),lyr_subsectors.id()]  # unlike documentation, use .id() instead of .getLayerId()      


##########################################################
        #Simple renderer approach (handles multiple layers)
##########################################################

        # Create image
        img = QImage(QSize(1600, 1200), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)

        # Set image's background color
        color = QColor(255, 255, 255)
        img.fill(color.rgb())

        # Create painter
        p = QPainter()
        p.begin(img)
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)            
        render = QgsMapRenderer()

        render.setLayerSet(lst)

        # Set extent
        rect = QgsRectangle(render.fullExtent())
        rect.scale(1.1)
        render.setExtent(rect)

        # Set output size
        render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())

        # Do the rendering
        render.render(p)
        p.end()

        # Export PNG image
        img.save(result_path + '/' + "map_" + scenario_id + '_' +  map_style + '_simple.png', "png") #previously from sty object sty['pdf']

    QgsProject.instance().clear()
```